# Качество аккумуляторов

Tags: железо

Купили ноут, Продавец сказал, что заряда будет хватать на 5 часов. Сейчас попробовал - хватило на 3 ч 53 м. Скажите, пожалуйста, это брак или допустимо? По-моему, попахивает браком: даже на 4 полных часа из 5 обещанных не хватило .

Comment: Попахивает не браком, а маркетингом!

Answer (score 1):

Время работы любой автономной системы зависит не от цифры на рекламном ценнике, а от потребляемого тока. Например, если батарея имеет ёмкость, скажем условно, 1 Ач, значит она будет отдавать 1 Ампер в течении одного часа (в реальности чуть меньше из-за КПД, но не суть). Так вот, расскажу про мой ноутбук, у него 8 ядер. Я могу как сейчас печатать текст и ноут потребляет 2 Ампера тока, а могу загрузить его по полной программе на все 8 ядер. Он будет съедать почти 20 Ампер тока и, следовательно, на своём аккумуляторе проработает в 10 раз меньше. Понимаете суть? - всё зависит от потребляемого тока, а он тем больше, чем более сложные задачи на нём решаются, чем ярче экран, чем больше фоновых задач (антивирусы всякие). Экран, кстати, действительно много жрёт, поэтому при работе ноута от аккумулятора обычно установлена настройка гасить экран через 3-5 минут бездействия пользователя (если не фильм включен).

Сделайте так: включите ноут и просто оставьте его БЕЗ использования, но чтобы не входил в спящий режим (пусть гасит экран, но не спит). Сколько он протянет?
А теперь включите так, чтобы он проработал без использования, но чтобы не гасил экран (в настройках надо убрать отключение экрана). Сколько протянет? Вот если эти цифры будут меньше заявленных производителем, то ищите ответ на свой вопрос у ОФИЦИАЛЬНОГО производителя вашего ноута, у вас есть такое право. Потому что в магазине вам могут сказать, что он работает год без подзарядки, а у официального производителя может быть чётко сказано (это должно быть в инструкции), что может там всего-то 3 часа. Потому что им, продавцам, за каждую впаренную вещь дают какие-то бонусы.

Comment: >Вот если эти цифры будут меньше заявленных производителем- Этих  цифр (кстати, точнее говоря, не цифр, а чисел: а цифрами записываются числа) в бумагах нет. А, это мне надо смотреть на официальном сайте производителя, понял.

Comment: @mathem1 , да, либо если нет на сайте, то звонить им туда на горячую линию и задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Всё относительно и зависит от многих факторов: нагрузки, яркости экрана, наличия беспроводных подключений и т.д.
HewlettPackard обещает моему ProBook 11 часов автономной работы. А на деле только 7-8 часов вытягивает, хотя ноутбук почти не нагружен (Embedded разработка).
Так что это нормально.